# Creating Binary Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I've got 3 training sets having 5 different events:
`list(c('e1','e3','e4'),c('e2','e4'),c('e1','e3','e5'))`

I don't know how many events will be there in my list. So I need to count them also. Here I have shown e1 to e5 events as an example. There can be m number of events where I need to find m also. How to find m?
In general, how to create **m-by-n binary matrix** in R where m-total number of events, n-number of training sets? **event-IDs might be random, not necessarily of 'eN' type like 'MX050331','IIF02002' etc.**

Answer (score 5):

```
# per the OP's second edit
# now assumes there are no events that haven't been observed at least once
tr <- list(c('e1','e3','e4'),c('e2','e4'),c('e1','e3','e5'))
e <- unique(unlist(tr))
sapply(tr, function(x) e %in% x)
```

Comment: And for once, I didn't have to transpose the result of `sapply`!

Comment: Or maybe you do... I transposed because I would have expected three rows as the result if three list items were given as the input....

Comment: If `lapply` returns vectors all of the same length, `sapply` treats them as _column_ vectors, so the result with be a matrix with nrows=length of each individual vectors, and ncols=number of vectors. In this case OP wanted a 5x3 matrix so it fits.

Comment: @Hong: if events are having some random IDs instead of 'eN' then how to approach?

Comment: @anu Rather than disussing arbitrary complications, perhaps you should put what you know about the events into your question.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
x <- list(c('e1','e3','e4'),
          c('e2','e4'),
          c('e1','e3','e5'))
t(sapply(x, function(y) {
  table(factor(y, levels = c("e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5")))
}))
#      e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
# [1,]  1  0  1  1  0
# [2,]  0  1  0  1  0
# [3,]  1  0  1  0  1
```

Obviously, you can drop the `t` if you prefer to not transpose it.

If the number and names of events is unknown, you can modify the function as follows:

```
t(sapply(x, function(y) {
  myLevs <- unique(unlist(x))
  table(factor(y, levels = myLevs[order(myLevs)]))
}))
```